# custom google search autosuggestion

Tags: google-custom-search

I have created a custom google search application for my website.

Below is the url

https://www.google.com/cse/

to create application.

Under the Auto complete section i have enabled autocomplete,but still it dont suggest me the options when i start typing on search box.

It suggest me only the keywords that We define under custom autocompletions.

SO my question is : Do we need to provide all the custom keywords that we want to autocomplete in search box or google just creates its own autosuggestion from the website ?

Answer (score 0):

It creates autosuggestions from the website, but it may take few days to collect all data. It also takes into account user's queries on your website.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer suggests, autocomplete can take a few days to begin working. In addition you must specify one or more specific sites / pages to which to restrict the custom search engine. On occasion, you may also have to specify that the CSE only search those site(s) / page(s) instead of simply emphasizing them in the results.